# Compound control onClickListener

Tags: android, custom-controls, onclicklistener

I have write this custom view control, this is the xml that I repeet 5 times.
I have write the onClickListener, but the problem is , how can recognize which button are pressed(there are 60 button)?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/a9p_09_11_00943" >

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnCount="8"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:rowCount="4" >

            <!-- prima riga  P1 R1 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R1"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R1"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R2 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R2"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R2"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R2"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R2"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R2"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R3 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R3"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R3"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R3"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R3"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R3"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R3"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <!-- seconda riga  P1 R4 -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C1R4"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C2R4"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnP1C3R4"
                android:layout_column="5"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:background="@drawable/add_64" android:contentDescription="@string/store_add" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C1R4"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C2R4"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtP1C3R4"
                android:layout_column="6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_txt_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:text="@string/store_void"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/store_1" />
        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is the container of coustom control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo
    android:id="@+id/ripiano1"
    android:tag="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo>

<com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo
    android:id="@+id/ripiano2"
    android:tag="2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo>

<com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo
    android:id="@+id/ripiano3"
    android:tag="3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo>

<com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo
    android:id="@+id/ripiano4"
    android:tag="4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo>

<com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo
    android:id="@+id/ripiano5"
    android:tag="5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the class for the control:

```
public class Ripiano_Frigo extends LinearLayout implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Context Ccontext;

    private static final int[] BUTTON_IDS = {
        R.id.btnP1C1R1,
        R.id.btnP1C1R2, 
        R.id.btnP1C1R3,
        R.id.btnP1C1R4,
        R.id.btnP1C2R1,
        R.id.btnP1C2R2, 
        R.id.btnP1C2R3,
        R.id.btnP1C2R4,
        R.id.btnP1C3R1,
        R.id.btnP1C3R2,
        R.id.btnP1C3R3,
        R.id.btnP1C3R4
    };

    private static final int[] TEXTVIEW_IDS = {
        R.id.txtP1C1R1,
        R.id.txtP1C1R2, 
        R.id.txtP1C1R3,
        R.id.txtP1C1R4,
        R.id.txtP1C2R1,
        R.id.txtP1C2R2, 
        R.id.txtP1C2R3,
        R.id.txtP1C2R4,
        R.id.txtP1C3R1,
        R.id.txtP1C3R2,
        R.id.txtP1C3R3,
        R.id.txtP1C3R4
    };      
    private ArrayList<ImageButton> buttons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
    private ArrayList<TextView> txtName = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    public Ripiano_Frigo(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Ccontext = context;
        loadViews();
    }

    public Ripiano_Frigo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Ccontext = context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.ripiano_frigo, this);

        loadViews();


    }

    private void loadViews() {
        int idt=0;
        for(int id : BUTTON_IDS) {
            ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(id);
            MyTag myTag = new MyTag(idt, BUTTON_IDS[idt],TEXTVIEW_IDS[idt], 0, 0);
//          button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//              
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View v) {
//                  int i = v.getId();
//                  final MyTag myTag = (MyTag) v.getTag();
//                  //if(v.getId()==BUTTON_IDS[0]){
//                   //     v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);     
//                   // }   
//                  Toast.makeText(Ccontext,myTag.loc+ " button "+v.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                }
//            });
            buttons.add(button);
            setMyTag(myTag, idt);
            buttons.get(idt).setOnClickListener(this);
            idt++;
        }
        for(int id : TEXTVIEW_IDS) {
            txtName.add((TextView)findViewById(id));
        }
    }

    public void setTxtName(String name, int index) {
        if((index < 0)||(index > TEXTVIEW_IDS.length))
            return;
        txtName.get(index).setText( name );
    }

    public void setMyTag(MyTag myTag, int index) {
        if((index < 0)||(index > BUTTON_IDS.length))
            return;
        buttons.get(index).setTag(myTag);
    }

    public void setClickListener(OnClickListener listener){
        for(int id = 0; id < BUTTON_IDS.length; id++) {
            buttons.get(id).setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(Ccontext, " button "+v.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

the result is like that:
[image]

in the main activity I use this code to create the control:

```
Ripiano_Frigo Ripiano1;
     Ripiano_Frigo Ripiano2;

Ripiano1 = (Ripiano_Frigo)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ripiano1);
            Ripiano2 = (Ripiano_Frigo)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ripiano2);
            Ripiano1.setTxtName("crema",0);  
            Ripiano2.setTxtName("cioccolato",5);
```

but when I click for example the first button to the left(first group), the return messege is the correct ID, all the button of first group respond correctly.
When click the the same button , but for the **second group** below, the return message is equal to the first button (R.id.btnP1C1R1).

how can recognize which button are pressed?

EDIT
I have tried this solution, I have added android:tag="1" to the first custom control and so on to the other,

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo rip1 = (com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo)findViewById(R.id.ripiano1);
        com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo rip2 = (com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo)findViewById(R.id.ripiano2);
        com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo rip3 = (com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo)findViewById(R.id.ripiano3);
        com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo rip4 = (com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo)findViewById(R.id.ripiano4);
        com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo rip5 = (com.bandweb.mycpstore.Ripiano_Frigo)findViewById(R.id.ripiano5);
        if(rip1 != null)
            Toast.makeText(Ccontext, "1 - button "+v.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if(rip2 != null)
            Toast.makeText(Ccontext, "2 - button "+v.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if(rip3 != null)
            Toast.makeText(Ccontext, "3 - button "+v.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if(rip4 != null)
            Toast.makeText(Ccontext, "4 - button "+v.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if(rip5 != null)
            Toast.makeText(Ccontext, "5 - button "+v.getId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

is a trick...

**EDIT**
this is the main class, in this class i would like to implement the onclick for the  button

```
public class Page2 extends Fragment 
{
    private static final String TAG = "Pagina2";
    View rootView, rootViewList;
    Context appContext,GappContext;
    Context appContextDialog;

     Ripiano_Frigo Ripiano1;
     Ripiano_Frigo Ripiano2;

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle outState) {      
          super.onCreate(outState);
          Log.d(TAG, "onCreate step 0");    
          // TODO Put your application initialization code here.
        }              

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView step 1");  

            return rootView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated step 3"); 
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            appContext = getActivity().getBaseContext();


            init(rootView, savedInstanceState);         
        }           


        void init(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){

            Ripiano1 = (Ripiano_Frigo)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ripiano1);
            Ripiano2 = (Ripiano_Frigo)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ripiano2);
            Ripiano1.setTxtName("crema",0);  
            Ripiano2.setTxtName("cioccolato",5);
            //Ripiano1.setClickListener(this);
            Ripiano1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("CLICKED!");
                }
            });

        }  //********************* end init****************************

    }
```

but the on click get only the event of the view and non the event of button...
how can get it here?

Comment: You can try gridview. And click listener on gridview

Comment: how? can you have some code to explain?

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the tags to the buttons in the xml layout instead of the code.

This will both keep the tags straight more easily, and will be a performance improvement.

Then, in the onClick handler, you can do v.getTag() to read the button's tag and use the tag to identify the button.

Comment: I have tried this solution, I have added android:tag="1" to the first custom control and so on to the other, watch the EDIT

Comment: In your edited code, you haven't made use of the tags at all. Note that you shouldn't have to do findViewById, just get the tag from the view parameter to onClick.

Comment: edit correct now, but i would like to find a great solution...Is possible to create a callback to the creator? (Ripiano_Frigo Ripiano1)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "the creator", or where you want the callback to be called from?

Comment: in the mainactivity i "create" the Ripiano_Frigo Ripiano1, and I would like to have the callback here (onclick) for the button pressed

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but of course, if you are creating a button, or otherwise have a reference to one, then you can add an OnClickListener to it.

Comment: please look ,I have edit with a new code, I would like to receive the event of button pressed on the Page2 class, is possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68036/discussion-between-andrea-bandiera-and-greybeardedgeek).